# Hi-res Program Time

Tags: c++, time, precision

I'm currently programming Tetris in C++. Right now I am at the stage where I have finished writing the program but I still need to fix a few bugs and optimize performance.

That being said, one of the flaws in my program is that it can only handle one key-press per second. I need it to handle at least three. You can see the flaw demonstrated by this code:

```
//Most headers only pertain to my main program.
#include <iostream>
#include <termios.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

//Timer function.
void *Timer(void*) {

    time_t time1, time2;

    time1 = time(NULL);

    while (time2 - time1 < 1) {
        time2 = time(NULL);
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main() {

    //Remove canonical buffering.
    struct termios t_old, t_new;
    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &t_old);
    t_new = t_old;
    t_new.c_lflag &= (~ICANON & ~ECHO);
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &t_new);

    const int STDIN = 0;

    struct timeval tv, tv1;
    fd_set readfds, readfds2, master;
    tv.tv_sec = 1;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;
    FD_ZERO(&readfds);
    FD_ZERO(&master);    
    FD_SET(STDIN, &readfds);
    FD_SET(STDIN, &master);
    char buffer[1];

    while(buffer[0] != 'q') {

        pthread_t inputTimer;

        pthread_create(&inputTimer, NULL, Timer, NULL);

        readfds = master;

        memcpy(&tv1, &tv, sizeof(tv));

        if (select(STDIN+1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &tv1) == -1) {
            perror("select");
        }
        if (FD_ISSET(STDIN, &readfds)) {
            buffer[0] = cin.get();
            cout << "You entered: " << buffer << endl;

        }

        pthread_join(inputTimer, NULL);


        cout << "Timed out.\n" << endl;

    }

    cout << "Game Over." << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

As you can see, the program operates by setting up a one second interval timer and timeval. Because both timers use ints to determine how much time has passed, they cannot be more precise than one second. How can I modify my program to be more precise?

My thought was to copy the value of `tv1` to a third value if a key was pressed and then wait for input again but for whatever value time that `tv1` was. For example if I press a key when there is only half a second left, the value `0.5` would be taken from `tv1` and copied to another variable. Then the program would only wait for half a second for input, instead of the full second. This didn't work, however, because `tv1` only ever equals `1` or `0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use `struct timeval` and `gettimeofday()` `in sys/time.h`. You can achieve microseconds resolution.

Manpage: http://linux.die.net/man/3/gettimeofday

Further info: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Elapsed-Time.html

**EDIT**:
In Linux (not portable to MinGW under Windows) you could also use `poll()` (see [here](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll)), which lets you wait for milliseconds. That would be more efficient because `poll` suspends the thread execution until time is out.

```
//Timer function.
void *Timer(void*) {
    poll(0, 0, 100); //Suspend thread for 100 ms. 
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

The `poll`function is declared in `poll.h`

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `pthread_join` suspends the main thread until the timer thread completes. You will therefore miss any user input that comes during or after the join. Since you are already using `select`, you might as well make use of the timeout built into the `select` statement. If you keep a watch of time elapsed, you can achieve the same effect without the timer thread.